# Bearings for a contra rotating tubes

Tags: bearings, propulsion

Consider a mechanical setup, in which there are two concentric tubes, both to rotate counter to each other ie in a contra rotating fashion. Inner tube runs clockwise, and outer tube runs counter clockwise. Is there any kind of bearing that I can use between the tubes to ensure smooth functioning of mechanism. Or just a plain bearing is effective to put in between the tubes, for smooth running. 
The rpm of inner tube is 1000 rpm, and outer is about 10000 rpm. So can I put any 
bearing with capacity of about 11000 rpm, work in this scenario, ie can i install 
any bearing in between the tubes, or are there specific application bearings to be used for the concentric contra rotating tubes.

Comment: Check out roller bearings, other questions force lubricated or not, side loading etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pretty much any bearing (rolling element bearing or journal bearing) that can take 11,000 rpm should be able to handle being placed in a differential configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My original comment as an answer : Check out roller bearings, other questions : will they need forced lubrication - is this possible ?  What is the required life? Will they be easy to change? Or replace complete unit. What are the loads that need to be supported end or side loading etc.